# Can't multiple destroy with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I need to multiple delete tasks with checkboxes, when i do this have an error
Have tasks and checkboxes for every task, when clicked on checkbox and then click the "Delete selected" button it must be deleted all checked tasks

> NoMethodError in TasksController#delete_multiple

undefined method `destroy'
here is my request

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Bc2lZKUDVOjkQ0DYTDNI8TVliMaDKb+z2wz46RJeFqFol8WyEABA8sAz+WPCQOD2V0SEyqSHAryuoYQ6nvk4sA==",
 "cb_tasks"=>["1", "3", "4"],
 "commit"=>"Delete selected"}
```

and 
my task_controller

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tasks/new
  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tasks/1
  # DELETE /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: 'Task was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  # multiple delete with checkboxes
  def delete_multiple
    @tasks = Task.find(params[:cb_tasks])
    @tasks.destroy() // **here is a problem**
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: 'Tasks was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :priority, :due, :done)
    end
end
```

my task.rb

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord

  def destroy
    Task.find(params[:cb_tasks]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Material destroyed."
    redirect_to tasks_url
  end
end
```

my index.html.rb

```
<%= form_tag delete_multiple_tasks_path, method: :delete do %>
  <div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
    <table >
      <tr>
        <td>Tasks</td>
      </tr>
      <% @tasks.each do |task| %>

        <tr>
          <td><%= check_box_tag "cb_tasks[]", task.id %></td>
          <td><%= link_to task.title, task %></td>-->
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>
<% end %>
```

my routes

```
  resources :tasks do
    collection do
      delete 'delete_multiple'
    end
  end
```

Why it can't undefined method `destroy' ?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: lets try the given solution below and let me know for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is below line

```
@tasks = Task.find(params[:cb_tasks])
@tasks.destroy() // **here is a problem**
```

You can modify this like below

```
Task.where(id: params[:cb_tasks]).destroy_all
```

I think will help

Comment: undefined local variable or method `params' in   def destroy
    Task.find(params[:cb_tasks]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Material destroyed."
    redirect_to tasks_url
  end

Comment: @asda111sd as i explained below that your model method `destroy()` doesn't know about `params[:cb_tasks]` so it will fail to execute here.

Comment: NameError in TasksController#delete_multiple \n 
undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Task:0x007fb3e079d268> \n Extracted source (around line #4): \n  def destroy \n Task.find(params[:cb_tasks]).destroy \n  flash[:success] = "Material destroyed." \n redirect_to tasks_url \n   end
\n Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"m+4ySAvygeoi+YioLvMmS78ZunrUZ8gyXujLJMKSFQX2tFKevvGV8AaJMROggI5M3Ti2dvPJdT0rRbf3TjU7FA==",
 "cb_tasks"=>["1", "3", "7", "9"],
 "commit"=>"Delete selected"}

Comment: @asda111sd  just comment your model `destroy` method and `@tasks.destroy_all` it will fire `delete` sql query for all of your records.

Comment: here is my model   def destroy \n
    Task.find(params[:cb_tasks]).destroy_all \n
    flash[:success] = "Material destroyed." \n
    redirect_to tasks_url \n
  end \n and error undefined local variable or method `params' for

Comment: @asda111sd did you try `@tasks.destroy_all` ? is it now working?

Comment: @asda111sd did it resolve your issue as well as your confusion? feel free to upvote/accept my answer below given in page.

Comment: @asda111sd this is not my answer that you accepted. :( scroll down page you will get at bottom my answer.

Comment: the correct answer is Task.where(id: params[:cb_tasks]).destroy_all

Comment: @asda111sd Ohh sorry it's too late, just come to the online & finally solved

Answer (score 0):

instead of overwrite `destroy` method in model side you can do this and i would suggest you not to overwrite `destroy` however if you overwrite destroy method than you are not passing `params[:cb_tasks]` to this method and in `Task.find(params[:cb_tasks]).destroy` this line fails to execute because it does not get `params[:cb_tasks]` here in model 
so you can do this like -

```
  def delete_multiple
    @tasks = Task.find(params[:cb_tasks])
    @tasks.destroy_all // **replace it**
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: 'Tasks was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I find how it just works. I deleted method destroy the model 
and in controller do this

```
def delete_multiple
  Task.where(id: params[:cb_tasks]).destroy_all
end
```

Thanks for all your answers, you are the best!